# Can't load angular-bootstrap module in boilerplate angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I started an AngularJS project to get a feel for it by starting with [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed).

I am trying to load up [angular-bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap), but when I add the the module in my app.js file dependencies:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ui.utils',
  'ui.bootstrap', //<------
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers'
])
```

I get the following error when I run my app:

```
[$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! 
You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. 
If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I have angular-bootstrap installed and the files are in my `app/bower-components` directory as:

```
├── angular-bootstrap
│   ├── bower.json
│   ├── ui-bootstrap.js
│   ├── ui-bootstrap.min.js
│   ├── ui-bootstrap-tpls.js
│   └── ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js
```

As per the set up from the installation instructions, I have bootstrap.css and angular.js referenced in my `index.html` file.

I know there was another question that asked about this same error in [Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! while Karma run in webstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696573/error-injectornomod-module-ui-bootstrap-is-not-available-while-karma-run) but that's for running Karma tests, I can't even get the module to load on just running the app.

Comment: Show us or link to your index.html page please?

Comment: Not a comment on your issue, but why do you need both `ui-bootstrap.js` and `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`? tpls is the superset, it is ui-bootstrap.js plus templates.

Comment: @PSL, that's just how it is after running `bower install angular-bootstrap`

Comment: @roy You included bootstrap after angular right?

Comment: @PSL - doh, that was it, with the answer below...ok that was my problem.

Comment: @roy Ok, so any angular application that you load must come after angular.js script reference, because they have dependency on angular. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have included the link to the js file

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/ui-bootstrap.css">`

Answer (score 0):

you should also add bootstrap (bower install bootstrap) to our app and includ

bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js  in our app